# Binary operator '|' cannot be applied to operands at addOrRemoveFontTraitWithName

Tags: xcode, swift2, uifontdescriptor

I am converting my Objective-c code to swift 2 and I am getting the following errors:

Binary operator '&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits' and 'UInt32'

Binary operator '|' cannot be applied to operands of type 'UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits' and 'UInt32'

This is my code: errors at the if { ... else {

```
func addOrRemoveFontTraitWithName(traitName: String, andValue traitValue: UInt32, ...) {

    var currentAttributesDict : NSDictionary = self.textView.textStorage.attributesAtIndex(selectedRange.location, effectiveRange: nil)
    var currentFont : UIFont = currentAttributesDict .objectForKey(NSFontAttributeName) as! UIFont

    var fontDescriptor : UIFontDescriptor = currentFont.fontDescriptor()
    var fontNameAttribute : NSString = fontDescriptor.objectForKey(UIFontDescriptorNameAttribute) as! NSString
    var changedFontDescriptor : UIFontDescriptor

    if (fontNameAttribute.rangeOfString(traitName).location == NSNotFound){
        var existingTraitsWithNewTrait : UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits = fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits | traitValue
        changedFontDescriptor = fontDescriptor.fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits(existingTraitsWithNewTrait)
    } else {
        var existingTraitsWithNewTrait : UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits = fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits & ~traitValue
        changedFontDescriptor = fontDescriptor.fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits(existingTraitsWithNewTrait)
    }
...
}
```

And i tried it with "traitValue: UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits" for the parameter "traitvalue"

```
    func addOrRemoveFontTraitWithName(traitName: String, andValue traitValue: UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits, ...)
```

Now the errors are

Binary operator '|' cannot be applied to two 'UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits' operands

Unary operator '~' cannot be applied to an operand of type 'UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits'

This error was already posted here, but no solution for me. It drives me crazy...:-(

Answer (score 2):

Use the rawValue which is UInt32

```
var existingTraitsWithNewTrait =
UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits(rawValue: fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits.rawValue | traitValue)
```

Comment: got the error: Cannot convert value of type 'UInt32' to specified type 'UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits' @megakilo

Comment: Please try the edited answer. Basically, you work on raw values (& or |)  then recreate a new struct.

Comment: hi megakilo, now the error in the next line
changedFontDescriptor = fontDescriptor.fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits(UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits(rawValue: existingTraitsWithNewTrait))
is "Cannot convert value of type 'UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits' to expected argument type 'UInt32'"???
No error with 
let existingTraitsWithNewTrait : UInt32 = fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits.rawValue | traitValue

Comment: i don´t understand... :-(

Comment: I found you missed the rawValue when creating the traits. `UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits(r‌​awValue: existingTraitsWithNewTrait.rawValue)`

Comment: oh, now i see it and understand. Many THX